# fetch the latest version number of a maven package programmatically

Tags: java, maven

I`d like to fetch the number based version number of a maven package programmatically - to be more specific: I need the number of the RELEASE version.

An example:

JUnit is a wellknown maven package. According to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit, the current RELEASE is 4.12.

So given the artifact identifier I'd like to receive the corresponding RELEASE version number (4.12 in this specific case). Since maven is some kind of a repository, I hope that there is an easy way for doing so.

I currently do have two different approaches that *might* work, however both are not satisfying.

1. I could create a pseudo java project that requires the dependency by maven. After mvn install it could be possible to get the version number from the jar-Files.
2. I could do a GET Request to mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit followed by some fancy regex ... definitely not a best practice

Edit:
And here is the magic number three:
http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:%22**groupid**%22+AND+a:%22**artifactid**%22&core=gav&rows=1&wt=json
returns a json with the number I've searched.

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear what you want to do but, if you want to be able to use the build version when executing the artifact built by the pom, the following should help.

With the resource plugin you can do token substitution in a resource.This means you can replace any string in a property file or even a java source file with the value of a maven property like ${project.version}.

It is not clear what version you want to have but:

- by using a property to specify the version of a dependency like ${junit.version} you can use the dependency version.
- by using the builtin project version property you can use the version of the current project.